# CSS-scaling picture to both height and width

Tags: html, css, image

I'm fairly new to CSS and having trouble with scaling a picture.

I have a series of images (that I do not control) that are part of a slide show.  Up until now, the images I received were all of a fairly standard size.  I used a style on the image element to size these to 85% of the visible window's height.

```
.image{
top: 5vh;
height: 85vh;
width: auto;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;}
```

This is inside a div that just has:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

this has worked fine.  The problem is that I just received an image that is quite wide, causing it to overlap content that sits left and right of the image.  I tried putting a max-width on the image style

```
max-width:85vw;
```

However, that caused the image to distort.

Is there a way that I can implement the following?  "Size the picture at 85% of the height of the viewport but do not exceed 85% of either dimension and don't distort the picture."

**Edit**

As I noted below, hiding the overflow didn't appeal to me.  I eventually got what I wanted with the following modifications to the code above.

```
.container
{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.image
{
  top: 5vh;
  max-height: 85vh;  /* this */
  max-width: 85vw;   /* and this */
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Place it in center of container, and hide overflow?

Comment: @sinisake, I tried that but I didn't particularly like the clipping of the picture.  I eventually got something I can live with by using a combination of min-height and min-width.  The critical thing was removing the height specification on the style.  Thanks for trying.